# Visual indication that the document needs saving in Microsoft Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007, user-interface, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Is there any visual indication that a document has been modified since it was last saved or opened in Microsof Office 2007 applications (Word, Excel, Powerpoint)? Ideally, I would like a star near the file name or somewhere in the status bar, to follow the custom set by most applications (including prior versions of Office). A solution involving a cost-free macro or plug-in is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything ready-made to do what you require, however the property you're after can easily be accessed through VBA using

```
[ThisWorkbook|ThisDocument|ActivePresentation].Saved
```

(in Excel, Word and PowerPoint respectively) which will return false if you have modified the document since it was last saved.

You mention a macro, so you may be able to write something yourself. If this is the route you have to take, perhaps try asking on StackOverflow?

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem is getting a visual indication out somewhere. I have no idea how to add something to the status bar, for instance.